# Function template deduction and initlializer_list

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, initializer-list, template-argument-deduction

I have the following function template:

```
template <typename K, typename V>
void f(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const K, V>> il)
{
    //...
}
```

I call the function as follows:

```
f({std::pair<const int,int>(1,2), std::pair<const int,int>(3,4)});    //(a)
```

and it works fine.

However, if I try and call it as follows:

```
f({{1,2}, {3,4}});    //(b)
```

it is not able to deduce the correct type, and I get a compilation error along the lines of:

```
'no matching function for call to 'f(<brace-enclose initializer list>)
note candidate is:
note: template <class K, class V> void f(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const K, V>>)'
```

If I call it as follows:

```
f({std::pair<const int,int>(1,2), {3,4}});    //(c)
```

the type deduction works, but if I try and call it as follows:

```
f({std::make_pair(1,2), {3,4}});   //(d)
```

I get the same compilation error as previously.

My question is:

Why does template type deduction work in (c) but not in (d)?

(Compiler is gcc v4.6.3, with flag -std=c++11)

I have looked at similar, older SO posts but they didn't appear to quite answer this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with **b)** is that the compiler isn't able to infer the types since something like

```
{1,2}
```

might as well be taken for an `initializer_list<int>`, the problem with **d)** is that [make_pair](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair) won't generate a `const int` for the first part of the pair

Comment: Yes, I'd figured with b) that couldn't infer, however, forgot about the non const int from make_pair. Thanks.

Comment: `{1,2}` isn't "taken for an `initializer_list<int>`", it's a non-deduced context unless it's paired with a `initializer_list<X>`. There's a difference (if the compiler actually deduced  `initializer_list<int>` from `{1, 2}` in all cases, then (c) won't compile).